# Designating no password for account in MySQL config file

Tags: mysql, mariadb, authentication, password

This is a theoretical question because having a DB account with no password is a terrible idea.

---

**Question:** Is there a way to designate an account with no password in the MySQL config file?

Answer (score 1):

*Technically*, yes. However, if the goal is to have an account used for certain tasks, you can create an account with a proper password, then place a file named `.my.cnf` in the home directory of the user who will use the MySQL account.

The `.my.cnf` file would look something like this:

```
[mysql]
user=sandeep
password=superSecretPassword!123
[mysqladmin]
user=sandeep
password=superSecretPassword!123
```

This would be slightly better than creating a user with no password.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is going so deep into a corner case that you are about to disappear into the crevices.

### ATTEMPT #1

Use [No-Login Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/no-login-pluggable-authentication.html)

### ATTEMPT #2 : Very Insecure

Create a mysql user

```
CREATE USER 'cornercaseuser'@'%'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'cornercasepassword';
GRANT .... TO 'cornercaseuser'@'%';
```

Stick these lines in the `/etc/my.cnf` itself (yes the config file for mysqld)

```
[mysql]
password='cornercasepassword'
```

Then you can login like this

```
mysql -ucornercaseuser
```

I have seen clients do this. VERY DANGEROUS !!!

### ATTEMPT #3

Use [socket authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/). At installation, `root@localhost` is configured to login without a password. Just create a user just like it.

For example, in MariaDB, when you create a user, you must still give it a password. However, you must declare the user as using both protocols. This is in the Documentation

```
CREATE USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket OR mysql_native_password USING 'invalid'
CREATE USER mysql@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket OR mysql_native_password USING 'invalid'
```

Why must such a user have both protocols ?

If you start mysqld with mysqld already running, the pid file disappears. This may or may not affect the socket file. If it does, `root@localhost` can no longer login checking for a socket file.

At that point, you must connect with the password and TCP/IP

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p --protocol=tcp -P3306
```